# IntegrityError when loading Django fixtures with OneToOneField using SQLite

Tags: django, sqlite

When attempting to load initial data via the `syncdb` command, Django throws the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: The row in table     'user_profile_userprofile' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: user_profile_userprofile.user_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in user_customuser.id.
```

There is a OneToOne relationship between the UserProfile model and CustomUser:

```
class UserProfile(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Running `./manage.py dumpdata user --format=json --indent=4 --natural-foreign` produces the following:

**CustomUser Model Data**

```
[
{
    "fields": {
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Test",
        "is_active": true,
        "is_superuser": true,
        "is_staff": true,
        "last_login": "2014-10-21T11:33:42Z",
        "groups": [],
        "user_permissions": [],
        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$12000$Wqd4ekGdmySy$Vzd/tIFIoSABP9J0GyDRwCgVh5+Zafn9lOiTGin9/+8=",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "date_joined": "2014-10-21T11:22:58Z"
    },
    "model": "user.customuser",
    "pk": 1
}
]
```

Running `./manage.py dumpdata user_profile --format=json --indent=4 --natural-foreign` produces the following:

**Profile Model**

```
[
{
    "fields": {
        "weight": 75.0,
        "created": "2014-10-21T11:23:35.536Z",
        "modified": "2014-10-21T11:23:35.560Z",
        "height": 175,
        "user": 1,
    },
    "model": "user_profile.userprofile",
    "pk": 1
}
]
```

Loading just the **CustomUser** model's initial data and then following up with **UserProfile** via load data works great, which suggests to me `syncdb` is attempting to load **UserProfile** before **CustomUser** has been loaded.

If the simplest solution would be to force the load order, what would the simplest way be to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should use `Migrations` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/ , they are ordered. But if you using older Django version then 1.7, install `south` https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Do you mean when loading data for the first time or when moving from one schema to another?

Comment: It's from Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/: 
"Automatically loading initial data fixtures
Deprecated since version 1.7: If an application uses migrations, there is no automatic loading of fixtures. Since migrations will be required for applications in Django 2.0, this behavior is considered deprecated. If you want to load initial data for an app, consider doing it in a data migration."